# Python with mod wsgi cannot nevigate beteween python files

Tags: python, mod-wsgi

I want that my wsgi.py will get an access to another dbHandling.py file's functions.
When I work with pyCharm all I need to do for 1 file will get an access of another class's functions is:

in wsgi.py file:

```
from dbHandling import dbHandlingclass
```

and then:

```
 dbHandlingclass().getEmployeeData()
```

But when I connecet to wsgi.py from my browser (address: localhost\wsgi) I get an error:

from dbHandling import dbHandlingclass\r
 [wsgi:error]  ImportError: No module named 'dbHandling '\r

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to add the path to that module to Python's module search path. Something along the lines of:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(__file__))
from dbHandling import dbHandlingclass
```

The relevant `mod_wsgi` documentation: https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ApplicationIssues#Application_Working_Directory